# Gradle project sync failed due to unresolved references

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle

Learning about Navigation between screens with Compose from `developer.android.com`. After downloading the starter code I get the following errors.

Usually changing the gradle versions fixes all my sync fails but today my luck has run out. I'm sure there is a ez fix that i dont know about. Hope that i can get some help.

```
git clone https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-cupcake.git
```

```
> Configure project :app
e: file:///C:/Users/Marco/AndroidStudioProjects/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-cupcake/app/build.gradle.kts:61:5: Unresolved reference: packaging
e: file:///C:/Users/Marco/AndroidStudioProjects/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-cupcake/app/build.gradle.kts:62:9: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: ...

e: file:///C:/Users/Marco/AndroidStudioProjects/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-cupcake/app/build.gradle.kts:63:13: Unresolved reference: excludes
e: file:///C:/Users/Marco/AndroidStudioProjects/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-cupcake/app/build.gradle.kts:63:22: Unresolved reference: +=

> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
`your text`
* What went wrong:
Failed to calculate the value of property 'namespace'.
Package Name not found in C:\Users\Marco\AndroidStudioProjects\basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-cupcake\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml, and namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace for the generated R and BuildConfig classes via android.namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:
```

Comment: is there a package name specified in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Hi Eliza thanks for the swift response. I don't see anything in the AndroidManifest.xml that looks like a package name being specified. I don't know if the problem is on my side or if its the starter code that was provided in the navigation part of the Compose course. I do not have a another system to test it on thats why I provided the git hub clone to see if other people have the same problem.

Comment: But its not the end of the world if  I can't find a solution. I can still learn the content and just apply it to another test app. Would just be nice to know what the cause is so that i dont feel as defeated (: . I only started coding 3 months ago so im still very new to everything.

Comment: I downloaded without a problem. Sometimes build just go wrong without an actual reason (welcome to Android xD). I'd suggest File -> Invalidate caches -> Restart. If that doesn't fix your problem try to re-import it (File -> New -> Import project). Hope it works!

Comment: I've also found this issue when using Navigation 2.5+ with Gradle 8+. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered same problem. follow these steps :-

1. In the error see there is a build.gradle.kts file. please Open it.
2. Now in build.gradle.kts file you will see a large script. In the script remove the packaging block (as it is not a recognized configuration block in the Android Gradle Plugin).
3. Hit try again and refresh.

   I hope it helps.